# Admin options from parent theme do not bind

Tags: child-theme, theme-options

I'm doing a child theme just to patch a bug in the parent one. It's the first time I do this.

I have :

- style.css <- mandatory file to load the parent style
- functions.php <-- mandatory file
- screenshot.png <-- the image load correctly
- content-foo.php <-- it used correctly

My problem is when I activated the child theme every admin options in the theme customizer do not bind anymore. Even if I save the backgound image or logo or any color again, the site and the preview do not recognize it.

I know I do not need to override header.php, index.php... : [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101484/use-admin-options-from-parent-theme-in-child-theme)

**style.css**

```
/*   
Theme Name: Foo Patches
Theme URI: https://... 
Description: To fix Foo theme.
Author: <a href="https://...">John Doe</a>
Author URI: https://...
Version: 1.0
License: Comercial
License URI: http://...
Tags: left-sidebar, right-sidebar, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, full-width-template, theme-options, translation-ready
Text Domain: Foo Child
Template: foo
*/

/* You can start adding your own styles here. Use !important to overwrite styles if needed. */
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foo_patches_enqueue_styles' );
function foo_patches_enqueue_styles() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'foo_style', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/style.css' );

}
```

So what happen ? Someone has got an idea ?

Comment: guess you are missing the functions.php
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Ok but what I need to do in functions.php because I need just the same options and normally it should load the parent's one, no ?

Comment: The links tells you the basic code you need in functions.php

Comment: I put an error_log in the parent's functions.php and it's loaded

Comment: I would like to avoid to copy unusefull code.

Comment: you dont have to add repetitive code; however, the 'Theme' - < 'Customization' is linked to the particular theme and you might have to redo them

Comment: So for functions.php even if the parent's one is loaded, you need to put a copy of one in your child theme ?!?!

Comment: Ok I saw in the wordpress tutorial, functions.php is mandatory but maybe just with the function to set parent style, it could be enough. Thanks for your help @Lucky Chingi.

Comment: The problem continues...I put my simple code.

Comment: Is your site live? What is the address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the parent PAID template does not work with the customizer page and use a submenu page to load options. Because just a bad user experience, I lost my time.[image]